# Spaces inside variable IN statement of a FOR loop in BATCH

Tags: batch-file

I want to retrieve and use elements (tokens) of a given .txt file to do something based on it :

```
set txtsource=D:\some path with spaces\source.txt
set picsdir=D:\other path with spaces

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in (%txtsource%) do (echo "%picsdir%\%%i" "%picsdir%\%%j")
```

Problem : this gives "System can't find the file D:\some."

2nd try :

```
set txtsource=D:\some path with spaces\source.txt
set picsdir=D:\other path with spaces

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ("%txtsource%") do (echo "%picsdir%\%%i" "%picsdir%\%%j")
```

Problem : this does not open/read the txtsource file properly, and in turn echoes the paths, instead of what is inside the source.txt.

3rd try :

```
set txtsource=D:\some path with spaces\source.txt
set picsdir=D:\other path with spaces

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('%txtsource%') do (echo "%picsdir%\%%i" "%picsdir%\%%j")
```

Problem : this says "'D:\some' is not recognized (...)".

Any idea how to make this work ?

Comment: `for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in("%txtsource%") do ...`

Comment: This works, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

*It's all about quoting!*

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "txtsource=D:\some path with spaces\source.txt"
Set "picsdir=D:\other path with spaces"

For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2 Delims=/" %%A In ("%txtsource%"
) Do Echo "%picsdir%\%%A" "%picsdir%\%%B"
```